# How to hide username and password in a $.getJSON call

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm using jquery $.getJSON with sensitive "pwd & user" parameters on client, how can I hide them or "serverside" this approach?

```
var rootUrl = "http://www.xxxx|.com/";
var jsoncall = rootUrl + 'Avis/List?contentType=json&' + param + "&sp.SortDirection=Desc&usr=myuser&pwd=8hjjhuddfiOOoS" + '&jsoncallback=?';

//        clearData();
//$.getJSON((param != '' ? param : url + 'jsoncallback=?'), (param != '' ? [] : $("#form1").serialize() + '&jsoncallback=?'), function(response) {
$.getJSON(jsoncall, function(response) {
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do the client will always see them. You could use POST but they will still be visible. I would recommend you sending them over HTTPS which will protect you from [Man-In-The-Middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks. If you want to hide them from the client you will need to create a bridge server side script between your domain and the distant resource and then send an AJAX request to this bridge script. So the username and password would be stored on the server and never visible to the client. Example:

```
$.getJSON('/myscript', $('#form1').serialize(), function(response) {
    // do something with the result
});
```

and it will be `/myscript` that will take care of delegating the request and passing any sensitive data to the remote resource.

Comment: thanks Darin, what will be myscript like? is it a server side script cs? in case it is what "sample code" can i use in asp net c# to replace getjson jquery's? i've implemented all site UI in jquery to achieve high speed, doing this bridge will compromise speed?

Comment: @charlypapa, if you are using ASP.NET you may take a look at the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class which allows you to send an HTTP request to a remote resource. So you could use this class in your server side script.